# My teachers treat me differenly b/c I have a mental illness. I don't know how to confront them

Tags: health

Lately, ever since I got back from the hospital, my teachers have been treating me much differently from the other students, and have been coming off as condescending to me. It has gotten so bad that some of my peers have been noticing confronting me about it. I do not know what to do about my teachers or my peers. Can you help me?

Comment: I would expect that your university has an office charged with working with you on such issues. They should deal with your teachers, I think. Go find them.

Comment: I have been working with them, but it has not impacted the teachers or students.

Comment: @CastleNumber2 Depending on what country you live in, not complying with a student disabilities office may be illegal or require the university to sanction the professor in some fashion. We cannot tell you what rules and policies exist to coerce the professor into not being a dick. I hope you get fair treatment, but we can't help you besides saying "keep pushing"

Comment: You say they are coming off as condescending; if they are in fact condescending you, that's one type of problem. Is it also possible they are trying to be compassionate/concerned but are going about it in a misguided/unhelpful way? The way to address this is going to depend a lot on that distinction.

Comment: Can you formulate your question in a form which is answerable on this particular stack?

Comment: Has your mental illness manifested itself in any kind of behavior that would otherwise be problematic?  Are you asserting any kind of entitlement for special treatment regarding assignments, grades, academic standards and duties?

Answer (score 1):

Stay calm, is the first thing to try to do. Approach the teacher and be polite, most teachers like either after of before class. Make sure they are not busy. Then bring up your concerns with the teacher. Try to be as well spoken as possible and be straight to the point.

With your peers, you can be more into the moment. Speak along the lines of, "hey, you don't have to speak to me like that." You know your peers, if you need to be more polite you should. Also, stay polite with your peers, explain the situation to those who listen. **Important** don't waste your time with those who don't.

An important note: You would not want to make someone feel super bad about it, because then they would also start treating you differently, but for different reasons.

Hope your situation improves